# MATLAB: how to solve this integral for getting expected value?

Tags: matlab, exponential, integral

I want to solve the expected value for `f(x)` with `x=[x1,x2]` follows uniform distribution. I tried this:

```
syms x r d x1 x2;
f=2*x*acos(x^2-d^2/2*x*(r+d)+d/x)*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-x^2/2);
int(f,'x',x1,x2)
```

I need a parametric approach. But Matlab fails to solve this integration in symbolic format. Any solution to that?

Comment: You have not given values for `r` and `d` for numerical integration, but the random values I tried, MATLAB does not fail numerically. It does fail symbolically, but well, you have some very complicated equation there

Comment: @AnderBiguri I set `r=15`,`d=40`,`x1=40`,`x2=70`. Matlab prints    `int((7186705221432913*R*acos(40/R - 44000*R + R^2)*exp(-R^2/2))/9007199254740992, R, 40, 70)` in output which is the original code. What were your inputs and what did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it numerically, you need to use a numerical function: `integral`

example:

```
d=40;r=15;
%define f as anonymous function 
f=@(x)2.*x.*acos(x.^2-d^2./2.*x.*(r+d)+d./x).*(1/sqrt(2*pi)).*exp(-x.^2/2);
integral(f,40,70)
```

This gives me 0, (because it is 0), but if you try, for example:

```
d=4;r=2
integral(f,0,10)

ans =

   2.4036 - 3.3624i
```

Comment: I appreciate you, in my problem `x1=d` and  `x2=d+2r`. But it gives me  `0` for some examples I tried. Need to work on my formulation.

Comment: @fhm Make sure you are not forgetting parenthesis after division (`d^2/(....)`?). Also, you can plot the function. As it is now, it gives complex values. You can plot it with `plot([real(f(x1:0.1:x2);imag(f(x1:0.1:x2)]')`

Comment: parenthesis are correct I believe. Adding further elaboration, the function would be `f=@(x)2.*x.*acos(((x.^2-d^2)./(2.*x.*(r+d)))+d./x).*(1/sqrt(2*pi)).*exp((-x.^2)/2);` where we need to integrate across `x~[d,d+2r]`.

Comment: Is the plotting code true? I get error over semicolon (`Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.`)

Comment: Well, I forgot a parenthesis, but you are probably capable of closing it, right? @fhm . Also, your new fucntion in the comments show that parenthesis were incorrect. In a computer 4/2*2 is (4/2)*2 **not** 4/(2*2)

Comment: I corrected the missing parenthesis. Yes, I already arranged all operators in the right manner. The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I meant returning zero for integrating `f = 2*x*acos((-d^2+x^2)/(2*x*(r+d))+d/x)*exp((-x^2)*(1/2))/sqrt(2*pi)`. The integration should return non-zero value when `x1=d` and `x2=d+2r`. (parenthesis are correct here as I checked the function in Maple software). So maybe I need to check the validity of my original function.

Comment: @fhm `exp(-40^2/2)` is zero. Not really mathematically zero, but so small, that a computer can not handle it. [Look how small that value is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(-40%5E2%2F2)). So yeah, your integral has such a tiny value that is zero

Comment: You are right. The smaller the `x`, the closer the exp function to 1. This exp function is a part of normal distribution pdf function. Since this problem is concerned with real-world scenario, I cannot get rid of the large `x` values. it actually can grow up to `500`. Do you have any idea by which I can hold the normal distribution pdf at the end?

Comment: @fhm The normal distribution pdf is `exp(-(x-mean)^2/(2*std)` If you have a `std` of `1` and a `mean` of 0, then you get your equation. In that case, its less likely to have an `x` of value 500 than what it is in real life to win the lottery 50 times in a row. My guess: your equation is mathematically wrong, nothing to do with matlab. If this answer helped, consider accepting it

Comment: Ander a question. let's set `d=30`, `r=10`. Define `f` as `f=@(x)2.*x.*acos(((x.^2-d^2)./(2.*x.*(r+d)))+d./x).*(1/((d+2*r)-d));`. Now the integration `integral(f,d,d+(2*r))` returns the same value as if `d=60`, `r=10` or `d=100`, `r=10`. The solution only depends on `r`. Why?